# Python connect to IRC function - must be integer

Tags: python, irc

I made a basic IRC bot that would join a certain channel and say a defined phrase, as part of learning Python. However, are there changes in the latest version of Python?

```
import socket

nick = 'TigerBot'
passdwd = '*****'
port = '6667'
net = 'irc.snoonet.org'
chan = '#WritingPrompts'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # Was ist da IRC Socket? 

sock.connect ((net, port)) # Open server connection

irc.recv (4096) # Buffer setup
irc.send('nick ' + nick + '\r\n') # What is your name?
irc.send('USER AffixBot AffixBot AffixBot :Affix IRC\r\n') #Send User Info to the server
irc.send('JOIN ' + chan + '\r\n') # Join the pre defined channel
irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + ' :Hello.\r\n') #Send a Message to the  channel

while True: #While Connection is Active
    data = irc.recv (4096) #Make Data the Receive Buffer
    if data.find('PING') != -1: # If PING
     irc.send('PONG ' + data.split()[1] + '\r\n') # Then PONG
```

Line 11 is the problem - apparently, what I've got down as a string needs to be an integer. How can I go about this?

Comment: You're declaring `port` as a string in the line `port = '6667'`. Try declaring it as an int with `port = 6667`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your definition of port to be an integer.

```
port = 6667
```

not

```
port = '6667'
```

In general, if you have an existing string value that needs to be an int for a specific call, you can cast by calling `int(str)`, which will return the value of str as an integer or raise a `ValueError` if it can't cast.